# Constexpr on member function pointer value - undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a problem with a simple reflection like mechanism in C++. I would like to have one template type, which should behave differently with different member function pointers as template arguments:

[Solution #1, by standard it is bad]

If I have a class template with a class type and its member function pointer, I cannot specialize partially to the member pointer being null, because I cannot specialize "non-type template argument with dependent type" (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization argument list [5])

```
template<class O, void(O::*foo)() = nullptr>
struct p
{};

template<class O, void(O::*foo)()>
struct p<O, nullptr>
{};
```

[Solution #2, GCC problem]

If I try to specialize to a deduced constexpr value, which reflects to the member pointer, I have different problems with the compilers. GCC8.2 x64 tells me that the `nullptr == foo` expression is not constant in the context: `p<A, &A::f> j;`. However ARM GCC8 says it is okay. I think it is some memory layout problem, that `struct A` is not complete at the time the template engine tries to evaluate a concrete function pointer.

```
template<class O, void(O::*foo)() = nullptr, bool = nullptr == foo>
struct p
{};

template<class O, void(O::*foo)()>
struct p<O, foo, true>
{};

struct A
{
    void f();
    p<A, &A::f> j;
};
```

[Solution #2 usage, MSVC problem]

It is strange that MSVC 19.5 x86 is okay with the above, it has another problem. It is working, while struct A is standalone, or it inherits from one struct. But when there are two base structs (X, Y), it dies with internal compiler error.

```
template<class O, void(O::*foo)() = nullptr, bool = nullptr == foo>
struct p
{};

template<class O, void(O::*foo)()>
struct p<O, foo, true>
{};

struct X{};
struct Y{};

struct A : X, Y
{
    void f();
    p<A> i;
    p<A, &A::f> j;
};
```

Clang7 works with all the above well.

Can anyone explain, if this is an undefined behavior, or is there any guide about this topic in the standard?

Comment: Note than in C++17, you might have `template <auto foo = nullptr>`  which might ease your ease your specialization and usage.

Comment: Please don't call your class `O`! Surely you can see the problem?

Comment: You may want to issue a bug report for ICE.

Answer (score 0):

This is [CWG 2127](https://wg21.link/cwg2127). Basically, we have this restriction in [[temp.class.spec]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#9.1):

> The type of a template parameter corresponding to a specialized non-type argument shall not be dependent on a parameter of the specialization.

Which basically means that we can't directly do the kind of `nullptr` specialization you want to do. Which is... lame. But any problem in programming can be solved by adding another layer of indirection right?

```
template<class O, void(O::*foo)(), bool is_null>
struct p_impl { /* non-null case */ };

template<class O, void(O::*foo)()>
struct p_impl<O, foo, true> { /* null case */ };

template<class O, void(O::*foo)() = nullptr>
using p = p_impl<O, foo, foo == nullptr>;
```

gcc on the other hand just seems to have a problem comparing a pointer to member of incomplete type. It rejects this:

```
template <bool> struct Z { };

struct C
{
    void f();
    Z<&C::f == nullptr> z; // not a constant expression
};
```

This is [gcc bug 56428](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56428), I think.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. i have just edited the question, easier to be referred to.

Comment: Solution #2 gcc problem is at your's, too, when you start using it as a member of a class using its type as "O": see: https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/DpSnwD


also the problem with msvc is there, when you use the default nullptr in the template and you try inheritance from more than one base class: 
one base class is okay: https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/1W-o3r
two are not okay: https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/EFHbti


my question is still about is it defined behavior, or is it a stupid question since compilers can decide how to process member function pointer template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're comparing a function pointer (that is not constant, as it may be known only at linking time) to `nullptr` (that is).

You can solve this by using `std::integral_constant` to generate the relative constant for such function type, and then you can compare it.

So something like (for basic **C++11**) is:

```cpp
template<class O>
using F = void(O::*)();

template<class O>
using NullF = std::integral_constant<F<O>, nullptr>;

template<class O, F<O> foo = nullptr,
    bool = std::is_same<std::integral_constant<F<O>, foo>, NullF<O>>::value>
struct p
{};

template<class O, F<O> foo>
struct p<O, foo, true>
{};

struct A
{
    void f();
    p<A, &A::f> j;
    p<A> k;
};
```

With **C++17** you can maybe just use a function with `if constexpr` checks:

```cpp
template<class O>
using F = void(O::*)();

template<class O>
using NullF = std::integral_constant<F<O>, nullptr>;

template<class O, F<O> foo = nullptr>
struct p
{
    p()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::integral_constant<F<O>, foo>, NullF<O>>)
        {
            // yay
        }
    }
};

struct A
{
    void f();
    p<A, &A::f> j;
    p<A> i;
};
```